# Is web2py suitable for a large public website?

Tags: python, web2py

Web2py looks like a very nice Python framework but I am wondering if it is suitable to use for a large public web site. What sorts of issues might I run into? I'm not worried about technical scalability so much as UI/UX limitations, ability to connect other components, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

web2py is a very capable web server application framework. UI/UX (User interface / Experience) limitations does not arises usually from a server framework.

There are quite a number of free application that demonstrates it's capabilities:

- http://www.web2py.com/appliances

If you want to compare it with other server frameworks, there are quite a few documents out there that you can read on.

- [Django, Turbo Gears, Web2Py, which is better for what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646002/django-turbo-gears-web2py-which-is-better-for-what)

The following discussion should add to information here

- [Anyone out there using web2py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809/anyone-out-there-using-web2py)

You have to be more specific to make a judgement or evaluate a server framework than what you have mentioned.

[Edit: based on comments]

While the examples in the link provided by mdipierro may not inspire confidence with regard to desired UI/UX solutions. It would be premature to consider that because of web2py or any other server framework. It might point to the fact that all these are implemented by a resource constrained team.

Comment: I also would not think that UI/UX would be too limited by the framework but after reviewing a number of sites and appliances it's hard not to come to that conclusion. Maybe stated differently: "Are there any Web2py-powered services that have been written about on TechCrunch?". It definitely looks like a nice framework for quickly building personal, CRUD-oriented sites. I'm trying to figure out if it is a reasonable choice for building a larger, public, consumer-oriented web site.

Comment: @pbreitenbach: I understand your concerns. How ever, I still believe that the reasons for this are different and not due to web2py.

Answer (score 5):

You might take a look at [this list of sites powered by web2py](http://web2py.com/poweredby).

Comment: Thanks. Tenthrow looked interesting initially but appears to be dormant. RadBox is a decent example. Most of the rest of the examples don't make me feel that good about the framework.